# An error shown while doin face detection in OpenCV 3.7.6

Tags: face-detection, opencv, python

This is my code.

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("Resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
img = cv2.imread("Resources/skirt.PNG")
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img,scaleFactor = 1.1,minNeighbors=4)


for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


cv2.imshow("Result",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Getting this error.

```
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: And what about this is confusing you?  The file "Resources/skirt.PNG" does not exist, and you didn't check for errors.

Comment: I have checked that, the file do exist.

Comment: Not from the directory where your code is running.  Do `print(os.getcwd())` to find that.